# Sending JavaScript array data to WhatsApp contact via link

Tags: javascript, whatsapp

I have a javascript array.
Example:

```
let newArrVal = [{"name" : "book",
"Price" : 18.99}, {"name" : "bag",
"Price" : 18.99}]
```

I have an HTML button and I want that HTML button to send this array of objects data to WhatsApp, how do I do it? If you want to send a message to WhatsApp, you should have &20 for the space separator.
For example wa.me/+1234455?text=hello%20world

Here is my code :

```
 function sendShoppingListToWhatsApp() {
    const shoppingList = cart.map(item => `${item.name.replace(/\s/g, '%20')}: $${item.price.toFixed(2)}`).join('%0A');
    const totalAmount = total.toFixed(2);

    const message = `Shopping%20List:%0A${shoppingList}%0ATotal:%20$${totalAmount}`;

    const whatsappURL = `https://wa.me/+6285271926369?text=${encodeURIComponent(message)}`;
    // window.open(whatsappURL, '_blank');
  console.log(whatsappURL)
}
```

I don't understand why it says Whatsapp API blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best if you used the [**`encodeURIComponent()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) method, where the return value is a new string representing the provided `uriComponent` encoded as a `URI` component. Also, the [**`JSON.stringify()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method to convert the array into `JSON` string.

See it in this example:

```js
(function() {
  let newArrVal = [{
    "name": "book",
    "Price": 18.99
  }, {
    "name": "bag",
    "Price": 18.99
  }]

  let urlEncodedData = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(newArrVal));
  console.log(urlEncodedData); // This data may be sent through a URL.
}());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
}
```

So, in the example above, you will see the URL encoded version of your array in the console.

Now, if you need to decode back your data, you may use the [**`decodeURIComponent()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) method.

```js
(function() {
  let urlEncodedData = "%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22book%22%2C%22Price%22%3A18.99%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22bag%22%2C%22Price%22%3A18.99%7D%5D";

  let urlDecodedData = decodeURIComponent(urlEncodedData);

  console.log(urlDecodedData);
}());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
}
```